# How to include libsignal-protocol-c in my Swift iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, cmake, swift-package-manager, signal-protocol

I would like to write something like `import SignalProtocol` at the top of one of my Swift files and then be able to call the C functions from [libsignal-protocol-c](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-c).

libsignal-protocol-c's README says: "When integrating into actual applications, you should not need anything beyond CMake. Alternatively, you may integrate the code using a build system of your choice."

I think I'd like to use the [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/) to integrate libsignal-protocol-c into my Swift iOS app. Is there a way to automatically generate a manifest file, ie, `Package.swift`, and a module map, ie, a `module.modulemap` file, from libsignal-protocol-c's CMake files? Or if I need to create these files manually, what should they include? Otherwise, how would I do this with CMake?

[How to import and use libsignal-protocol-c in an existing .xcodeProj?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56934749/242933) is a similar question but for Objective-C projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can import libsignal with CocoaPods, see https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal/blob/main/swift/README.md

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure its an answer but I'm going to start using https://github.com/christophhagen/LibSignalProtocolSwift. Seems like a good start.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that project before, but I chose not to use it because its README says: "This Swift library is intended for educational purposes only". Plus that project is also not a [Swift package](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages).

Comment: Hello, are you able to find a solution regarding it ?